# DataContext from DLL has no Dispose() method

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have created a DLL which contains my LINQ DMBL files, which I have set as a reference in another project and is allowing me to interact with the database without problems.

However, the DataContext is missing the Dispose() method, and when I try to wrap a using around it it tells me that it is not implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable.

Is there something I'm missing here, as the Dispose() method is available in the DLL project. Is it somehow handled differently when the DataContext accessed via a DLL?

Many thanks

Comment: The access modifier for your Dispose method is probably not correct. Make sure it is set to public and not private, internal or protected.

If you only have a protected override for your Dispose like `protected override Dispose()` you may need to call Dispose explicitly through `((IDisposable)myDataContext).Dispose()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very weird. There should be no (big) difference between referencing dll and project in VS as you can see in properties of reference. The path points to dll in bin/debug (or bin/release - depends on build configuration) if it is referenced as project.

Assure that you have referenced the System.Data.Linq assembly.

If I try to create DBML in my VS 2008 - .NET 3.5 I see that datacontext class generated by dbml generator inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext which implements IDisposable.

Comment: That's it, it was as you suggested that I hadn't referenced System.Data.Linq. It automatically gave me Xml.Linq but I hadn't twigged I didn't have Data.Linq. Many thanks!

Comment: Give a try to ReSharper IMHO it's worth the money. It will help you (not only) in such situations.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion, there's a 30-day free trial so I will give it a go